# BeautifulSoup - code from inspect element

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've got page, which has got 2 different HTML code. When I clicked view page source, i've got the same code that in BeautifulSoup but I'd like to see code from inspect element. How?

Comment: What do you mean by 'inspect element'?

Comment: Inspect element works on client and Beautiful soup works on server.I think what you want to do is to use a server side debugging tool to debug Beautifulsoup (pdb?)

Answer (score 2):

I think the html in «inspect element» of firebug or dev tool of chrome is the html after javascript processing so you won't be able to have the same javascript in beautifulsoup

You can interpret the javascript linked to the page and retrieve the html content it may be possible with testing tools like https://github.com/kanzure/pyphantomjs or directly using http://casperjs.org/ or directly by using http://www.gnu.org/software/pythonwebkit/